# SQL: Select a Column where Column is has Special Characters

Tags: jquery, sql

I'm working on a Migration Script wherein I need to extract all client address.
The address is only allowed to contain the following characters **a-z 0-9 A-Z** and special characters **' (  )  +  ,  -  .  :** and the rest should be replaced with white space.

I need to perform a Select Query wherein I need to get all the address that has other characters present except the allowed characters

```
Select address from client_info where address like '%`~!@#$%^&*_{}[]<>?/%'
```

the idea is something like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `REGEX` IN MySQL

```
Select address from client_info WHERE address REGEX '[^-a-zA-Z0-9.,()%+]'
```

In `SQL` you can use

```
Select address from client_info WHERE address LIKE '%[^0-9a-zA-Z ]%'
```

`^` symbolizes `NOT` - it will fetch the characters other than `0-9` or `a-z` or 
`A-Z`.

Comment: No worries, please upvote answers which you find helpful.

Answer (score 1):

In MS SQL:

```
SELECT address FROM client_info WHERE address LIKE '%[^a-zA-Z0-9]%'
```